# Multiple subtotals - Rollup order of fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run a query that aggregates data, groups the results by  several different fields, and extract **all** relevant "SubTotal" permutations. (similar to CUBE() in MSSQL)

When Using `Group By Rollup()`, I get only permutations according to the order of the `Group By` fields in the `Rollup` function.
For example the query below (runs on a public dataset), it returns subtotal by year, or by year and month, or by year, month and medallion... but it doesn't subtotal by medallion.

```
SELECT
  trip_year,
  trip_month,
  medallion,
  SUM(trip_count) AS Sum_trip_count
FROM
  [nyc-tlc:yellow.Trips_ByMonth_ByMedallion]
WHERE
  medallion IN ("2R76",    "8J82",    "3B85",    "4L79",    "5D59",    "6H75",    "7P60",    "8V48",    "1H12",    "2C69",    "2F38",    "5Y86",    "5j90",    "8A75",    "8V41",    "9J24",    "9J55",    "1E13",    "1J82")
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(trip_year,
    trip_month,
    medallion)
```

My question is:
What should I do in order to get all different permutations of "Sub Totals" in a single query results.

Already tried: Union with similar query but with different order, it works, but not elegant (it would require too many unions).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on both counts.  In BigQuery, [`ROLLUP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupbyrollup) respects the hierarchy treating the listed fields as a strictly ordered list.  Their order will not be changed during aggregation.

The [`CUBE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx) aggregate commonly found in other SQL environments is unordered and in fact aggregates every possible order/subset of its listed fields.  At this time, `CUBE` has not been implemented in BigQuery.  The workaround you suggest is also what I would suggest.  `UNION` all result sets from `ROLLUP` using each permutation of its contained fields.  Albeit not ideal, you should get the same results.

In short, `UNION`s of several queries with different permutations of `ROLLUP` fields is the **only** way to achieve this at the moment.  The downsides are as you state that this may be difficult to maintain and can be more expensive in queries.

If you would like to see `CUBE` implemented in BigQuery, I strongly encourage you to file a feature request on the [Big Query public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).  Be sure to include a thorough use case in this request.

**UPDATE**: To support the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=582) filed by the OP, please ***star*** it and you'll receive notifications with updates.

Comment: Does this address the question adequately?

Comment: The answer is clear, but it does not resolve my problem. Union all is not an option. It requires n! repitions of the same query. If i have 9 grouping fields, the wuery becomes impossible to mainatain.

Comment: I agree that this is solution inefficient, more difficult to maintain and can be costly.  The workaround you propose however, is currently the **only** way of getting the aggregates you seek in a single query.  Hence, the recommendation to file a feature request.  I've updated my answer to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, Please vote: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=582